# CSS media queries - confused about overlap and order

Tags: css, wordpress, media-queries, overlap

I'm having a bit of trouble with my media queries.

Building a site using a purchased responsive wordpress theme, and am now customising it.

I'm running into an issue where, because of how the design behaves over a range of screen widths, I am using media queries to make adjustments whenever the design breaks.

Trouble is, various elements are breaking in different ways at different widths (not surprising).

So instead of getting a nice, exclusive range of media query sizes (eg: max-width: 480px, min-width: 481px --> max-width: 780px, min-width: 781px --> max-width: 960px, minwidth 961px) it's turning into an overlapping mess of queries.

Here is a sample of what I've got in my CSS so far, with CSS removed just to save space:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 961px) {
    /* upto 961px */


@media only screen and (min-width: 885px) and (max-width: 961px) {
    /* 885px upto 961px */


@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 884px) {
    /* 768px upto 884px */


@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    /* upto 767px */


@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
    /* Shrinks top nav text size for smaller screens*/


@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 550px) {
    /* Adjusts search bar location*/


@media only screen and (max-width: 565px) {
    /* Toggles correct Justified Image Grid for home page buttons */


@media only screen and (min-width: 566px) and (max-width: 721px) {
    /* Toggles correct Justified Image Grid for home page buttons */


@media only screen and (min-width: 722px) and (max-width: 902px) {
    /* Toggles correct Justified Image Grid for home page buttons */


@media only screen and (min-width: 903px) {
    /* Toggles correct Justified Image Grid for home page buttons */
```

Pretty messy huh? Please be nice, am still learning this stuff :)

So my main problem now is: the elements I'm controlling with the last 4 media queries (targeting the Justified Image Grid) contain very simple declarations - basically making certain elements display or not. I thought I'd defined these queries fairly exclusively, but they are not working the way I expect them to.

Is the problem possibly with my mess of other queries? (Even though the Justified Image Grid are not referenced in other queries?)

More than happy to take suggestions on how to handle queries in this kind of situation, which I'd imagine happens quite frequently with web builds...

EDIT:
Here is the link to the test page: http://dev.thecyclery.net.au/home-test/
There are two image grid elements, and I only want to display one at a time.

Thanks!
Jon

Comment: To be honest, the need for so many queries suggests to me that the layout is not very practical for modern web conditions. I rarely have more than two media query ranges. I'd hate to have to maintain more than that.

Comment: You didn't say how you expect them to work and how they're not working, though. I think the issue is not in the queries. Post a link to the website and/or a screenshot of the issue. —— Those media queries seem fine, you can define as many as you need, even if they overlap. You don't need to lump all the rules in a few preset media queries like others may suggest.

Comment: Excellent point @bfred.it. Here is a link: http://dev.thecyclery.net.au/home-test/ ------ You can see that there are two image grid elements on the page, but due to some limitations of the plugin I need to call differently configured versions in, as they break at certain page widths. So I want to only see one at any given width. But despite my media query rules, sometimes they both display. Hope this helps clarify my issue...

Answer (score 1):

one way to simplify things a bit is to remove the min-width portions of the queries that have both a min and a max. Then while using only max-width queries you order them from largest to smallest.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 961px) {
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 884px) {
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
}
```

These will automatically override each other when the screen gets below each respective setting.

Personally I only use the max-width settings and adjust them accordingly, hopefully you can get away with the same thing if you set it up correctly.

One reason that you may be having trouble is that if two queries have some of the same size parameters (overlapping conditions) whichever one is located last will take precedence over the other, and this might not be your intended outcome.

(Also, my personal experience with purchased wordpress themes has been less than satisfactory, you are typically better off customizing _s or one of the twenty___ themes that come with wordpress. The trouble with purchased themes is that they are usually designed with a specific intent (or specific plugins)... an intent that is almost never the same as your own intent.)

Comment: Thanks Joseph - this is a good option to consider. But what about this scenario: say there is a range of screen widths somewhere in the middle (760px-920px, just for arguments sake) where I need to make some adjustments. But outside this range, both above AND below, the original CSS is fine. I would then have to re-define my original CSS parameters in a max-width: 759px query, to offset the changes made in the previous max-width: 920px statement? (sorry, not trying to be picky at all - this is actually the case with my site).

Comment: I suppose that in such a scenario you would be correct, but I have never run into that specific case myself. In theory 'min and max together' should work fine, but in practice (and across browsers) I am not sure and you might have to redefine things by having two media queries just like you said.

Comment: OK, fair enough. I think I am in a little bit of an odd situation, trying to make a plugin do something it might not be entirely intended to do... and now having to wrestle it into submission - always fun!